# SwiftUI .sheet view resizing issue (testing on macos)

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-ventura

I have the following sample code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    @State private var hmm = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    hmm.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                if hmm {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                        Text("Some Text")
                        Text("Some Text")
                        Text("Some Text")
                        Text("Some Text")
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button {
                showModal = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the sheet appears, the size is correct.
[image]
When I toggle the button, the size correctly recalculates based on the UI elements that disappeared.
[image]
When I toggle again, the sizing is incorrect and does not seem to account for the newly visible items. How can I get the sheet to resize properly?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, hopefully this helps someone. After hours of search, i've found this seemingly unrelated post: [How to get Text width with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888495/how-to-get-text-width-with-swiftui)

Just like in the accepted answer of the referred post, I've added `.fixedSize()` to my `VStack` which has fixed the sheet's resizing issue.

```swift
if hmm {
    VStack {
        Text("Some Text")
        Text("Some Text")
        Text("Some Text")
        Text("Some Text")
        Text("Some Text")
    }
    .fixedSize()
}
```

Comment: This is the best you can do right now @LostBalloon